# r - Extract subsequences with specific time increments

Tags: r, datetime, time, subsequence

I have a data frame `df`. It has several columns, two of them are `dates` and `serial_day`, corresponding to the date an observation was taken and MATLAB's serial day. I would like to restrict my time series such that the increment (in days) between two consecutive observations is 3 or 4 and separate such blocks by a NA row.

It is known that consecutive daily observations never occur and the case of 2 day separation followed by 2 day separation is rare, so it can be ignored.

In the example, `increment` is shown for convenience, but it is easily generated using the `diff` function. So, if the data frame is

```
   serial_day   increment 
1      4           NA
2      7           3 
3      10          3
4      12          2
5      17          5
6      19          2
7      22          3
8      25          3
9      29          4
10     34          5
```

I would hope to get a new data frame as:

```
    serial_day                      increment
1      4                                NA
2      7                                3
3      10                               3
4      NA ## Entire row of NAs          NA
5      19                               NA
6      22                               3
7      25                               3
8      29                               4 
9      NA ## Entire row of NAs          NA
```

I can't figure out a way to do this without looping, which is bad idea in R.

Comment: Shouldn't row 6 in the first `df` be deleted too? The increment in that row is smaller than 3. If I understand your description correctly, you wish to keep only rows where the increment was either 3 or 4, right?

Comment: @KenS. I'd like to keep row 6 in the original data frame, since the time increment from 6 to 7 is 3.

Answer (score 1):

First you check in which rows the increment is not equal to 3 or 4. Then you'd replace these rows with a row of `NAs`:

```
inds <- which( df$increment > 4 | df$increment < 3 )
df[inds, ] <- rep(NA, ncol(df))

#    serial_day increment
# 1           4        NA
# 2           7         3
# 3          10         3
# 4          NA        NA
# 5          NA        NA
# 6          NA        NA
# 7          22         3
# 8          25         3
# 9          29         4
# 10         NA        NA
```

This may result in multiple consecutive rows of `NAs`. In order to reduce these consecutive `NA`-rows to a single `NA`-row, you'd check where the `NA`-rows are located with `which()` and then see whether these locations are consecutive with `diff()` and remove these rows from `df`:

```
NArows <- which(rowSums(is.na(df)) == ncol(df))       # c(4, 5, 6, 10)
inds2  <- NArows[c(FALSE, diff(NArows) == 1)]         # c(5, 6)
df     <- df[-inds2, ]

#    serial_day increment
# 1           4        NA
# 2           7         3
# 3          10         3
# 4          NA        NA
# 7          22         3
# 8          25         3
# 9          29         4
# 10         NA        NA
```